# function that push_back value to vector in c++

Tags: c++

I am newbie in c++. I wanna create function that `push_back` value to vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pushVector ( vector <int> v, int value){
v.push_back(value);
}

int main(){
vector <int> intVector;
pushVector (intVector, 17);
cout << intVector.empty(); // 1
}
```

As you see, my function don't `push_back` value in vector. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `vector<int>& v` job done.

Comment: "Pass by value" vs "pass by reference", look it up.

Comment: Your mistake is trying to wrap `push_back` in the first place. Why do you do that?

Comment: @jrok I do not understand your question :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to pass the vector to the function by reference. The way you wrote the function, it makes a copy of the vector inside its body, and the vector remains unchanged outside of the function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
void pushVector ( vector <int>& v, int value){
v.push_back(value);
}

int main(){
vector <int> intVector;
pushVector (intVector, 17);
cout << intVector.empty() // 1
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) is a concise explanation of the issue.

Comment: Ty for answer. Where can i find information about using this "&" symbol in c++ ?

Comment: @OrangeFox in literally any C++ book in-print since the language was invented. [See this list for suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)